# How can I execute the command of routines JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I need to execute the command -

```sql
SELECT sbcm_ref.process_time_reports_direct_buf_portion(100)
```

`process_time_reports_direct_buf_portion` is a class of Routines package in the sbcm_ref schema.

How can I do it?
Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're already using the code generator. Now you can just use that generated method in the generated `Routines` class like this:

```java
ctx.select(Routines.processTimeReportsDirectBufPortion(100)).fetch();
```